# Counting the total number of elements in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Looking to count the total number of elements in a CSV file using Pandas in Python. So if a csv file has 500 elements, I would want to return 500.

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)

tick = df.index(["EventID"])
ticketNum = tick.size
print("There were", ticketNum, " film permits.")
```

Attempted to use index.size but unfortunately does not work. Is there any other method to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use: len(df)

Comment: That worked. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply rows and column number:

```
ticketNum = df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows, just use `len(df)`.

Or distinct items, `df["EventID"].nunique()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use len(df) to find the length.